# C++ mouse functions not responding, Trying to create a clicking simulator

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

//void MouseRetracer(POINT mousePos, int noOfSaves, int delay)
//{
//  
//}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Enter delay between 2 clicks... ";
    int delay;
    std::cin >> delay;
    std::cout << "Hover the mouse to the desired location and press 'k'...\n";
    //std::cin.get();
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to start taking inputs!!!" << std::endl;

    bool quit = true;
    int noOfSaves = 0;
    POINT mousePos[100];

    while (quit)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            char kbKey = _getch();
            if (kbKey == 'k')
            {
                GetCursorPos(&mousePos[noOfSaves]);
                std::cout << noOfSaves + 1 << " positions saved...\n";
                noOfSaves++;
            }
            if (kbKey == 'q')
                quit = false;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "DO NOT move mouse now!" << std::endl;
    //MouseRetracer(mousePos, noOfSaves, delay);
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfSaves; i++)
    {
        //std::cout << mousePos[i].x << '\t';
        Sleep(delay);

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, mousePos[i].x, mousePos[i].y, NULL, NULL);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, mousePos[i].x, mousePos[i].y, NULL, NULL);

        std::cout << i + 1 << "th save clicked!\n";
    }

    /*std::cout << "Do this again? (y/n)\n";
    char repeat;
    std::cin >> repeat;

    switch (repeat)
    {
    case 'y':
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 'Y':
        system("cls");
        break;
    default:
        return 0;
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

The above code can take inputs properly i.e. it creates `POINT` struct and saves data `mousePos[0]`, `mousePos[1]`, etc. correctly(I checked via Visual Studio 2019 debugger) but it cannot simulate the clicks using `mouse_event()`. There are no errors or warnings. The problem seems to be `mouse_event()` even though it is working fine in other programs where `POINT mousePos;` is used. Using `POINT mousePos[100]` seems to be giving trouble.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider to post a question with runnable code, so people could work on the question easier. Otherwise, we just keep guessing what you want / need. please check also [how_to_ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @dboy Can you check it now, I added the full code.

Comment: [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event): *"This function has been superseded. Use `SendInput` instead."*

Comment: but it works for other programs where ```POINT mousePos;``` is used. Defining ```POINT mousePos[100]``` seems to give the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SetCursorPos` to set cursor position and then use `mouse_event` to send mouse button click event. The following is the working code for me. You can have a try.

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfSaves; i++)
{
    Sleep(delay);

    SetCursorPos(mousePos[i].x, mousePos[i].y);

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, mousePos[i].x, mousePos[i].y, NULL, NULL);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, mousePos[i].x, mousePos[i].y, NULL, NULL);

    std::cout << i + 1 << "th save clicked!\n";
}
```

**Note: 
It is suggested to use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead of `mouse_event` because this function has been superseded.**